# use socket to send data on internet

Tags: c#, sockets

When I send data using socket in C# on LAN, everything works fine, but how do I send my data over the internet. How to send while the sever I create uses the ip from my compute (private ip)

Can someone suggest on how can I achieve this, basically I should be able to send data anywhere over the internet, not just on LAN.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you are trying to get clients to connect to you local tcp/ip server, you will need to map through a port from your router to your pc. There is plenty of information on the internet regarding this

Comment: you mean i should research about NAT?. I mean ,i want to connect two computer and send data each other. In an easy way, I am making chess games. And dark want to play on 2 different computers.

Answer (score 0):

These days most computers have a router with a firewall between them. Routers, via secreuity design, stop direct access to the computers behind them and their local network.

Yes you will either have to

1. configure the router to map through a specific port to one of your computers.
2. Or, the more common way to do this is using a central hub, ie a Web service as an intermediary. This way no firewall are needed as both computers are only connecting one way (out). You could use a wcf service or Web api or many technologies to achieve this and usually you'd use a database to store you game state which makes it persistent